# Laravel always gets empty from JSON post

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on Laravel version 5.2. I've been trying to get json data from post. I always get empty data. I also have tried to use solutions found on the internet but there's nothing works. for example,

```
 1. $request->json()->all();
 2. Input::get('data');
 3. $request->get('data');
 4. $request->data;
 5. Input::all();
 6. json_decode(request()->getContent(), true);
 7. json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
 8. json_decode(request()->get('payload'));
 9. json_decode($request->get('payload'));
 10. $request->input('data');
```

Here is my javascript code,

```
    $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: url,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
    },
    data: {'data':'foo'},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And here is my laravel code,

```
public function postJsonData(Request $request){

    //several methods I am trying to use.
    $data = $request->data;

    Log::info($data);

    return json_encode($data);
}
```

Now I really have no ideas to move on. I really need help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried using `data: {data:'foo'},`?

Comment: I think everything is right, except URL. Try posting your ```Route``` here. Also, in the JS Variable ```url```, try writing ```var url = "{{url('your/url')}}"```.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the JSON payload by POST method so in that case you can do something like this

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

You need to stream the data, Let me know if it works for you